# Batch retag all questions with [google] [analytics] to [google-analytics]

Tags: support, retag-request

This morning, within the space of about 10 minutes, I've seen three questions tagged [google](/questions/tagged/google) and [analytics](/questions/tagged/analytics). I retagged them [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics).

I've just done a search, and **there are [another 254 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+analytics) like this**.

Can somebody run a SQL query (or use some other batch retag tool I don't know about) to retag them all with [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics) and strip the other tags?

Comment: Even I found a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060916/event-tracking-not-working) tagged with `google` , `analytics` and `google-analytics` `:)`

Comment: I did the same for `twitter+bootstrap` vs `twitter-bootstrap` few days ago :)

Comment: This led me to asking: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178438/183189

Comment: Oh no! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304839/tack-anchor-link-with-google-analytics?noredirect=1, a locked post, is preventing google+analytics from being unused :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Job done.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analytics+google)

I wasn't the only one to retag since I saw about hundred questions gone without an action from me.

By the way, I came to a strange situation with [referrer](/questions/tagged/referrer) & [referer](/questions/tagged/referer). Don't know what to do with that..