# Some suggestions for you to retag to help purge [google]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

[google](/questions/tagged/google) (the tag, that is) is a monstrosity. Evil, in fact. See [Should the [google] tag be removed and blacklisted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178438/should-the-google-tag-be-removed-and-blacklisted) The answer people are gravitating towards is very definitely "yes", and with good reason.

**However:** [google](/questions/tagged/google) (the tag, that is) is growing at a frightening rate, and if we want to kill it, we need to act fairly rapidly.

Here are some fairly clear-cut ones where work can be done comparatively quickly:

- [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [drive](/questions/tagged/drive) ([google+drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+drive)) → [google-drive](/questions/tagged/google-drive)
- [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [maps](/questions/tagged/maps) ([google+maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+maps)) → [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [markers](/questions/tagged/markers) ([google+markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+markers)) → [google-maps-markers](/questions/tagged/google-maps-markers) (take out the [map](/questions/tagged/map)/[maps](/questions/tagged/maps) while you're there)
- [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) ([google+spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+spreadsheet)) → [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)
- [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) ("documentation", you say? "docs" is an alias for it. [google+documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+documentation)) → [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) or [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet), occasionally both
- [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [maps](/questions/tagged/maps), [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [map](/questions/tagged/map) ([google+maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+maps), [google+map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+map)) → [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) (plus potentially some of its subtags): LOTS.

Really, as a generalisation:

- [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [any-product-name-you-can-think-of](/questions/tagged/any-product-name-you-can-think-of) → [google-thingummy](/questions/tagged/google-thingummy)

A strategy I find to work quite well is to start off by looking at the ones that have both forms—for example, [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [maps](/questions/tagged/maps) + [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) ([google+maps+google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+maps+google-maps)). These you can typically just remove the surplus tags on, so they're faster. Then you can go back and alter the tags on the remaining ones.

**So, my appeal is this:** help us kill [google](/questions/tagged/google) (the tag, that is).

---

(Then after that there's the meta tag [google](/questions/tagged/google) which needs to be cleaned up in just the same way, but it hasn't grown quite so unweildy.)

Comment: Hmm... What about [google] + [android]?

Comment: @undo: In what context?  We already know that Google wrote Android, and that fact doesn't seem material to most questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm meaning cases where there is already a suitable tag. Some, like `android` or `hangout` (eek, should be `hangouts`) are a tag of their own. If coupled with the `google` tag, the latter should typically just be removed. But cases like `maps`: that's generic, while `google-maps` is specific.