# Make it clearer when a tag is disallowed

Tags: feature-request, tags, blocked-tags

Looking at the following screenshot, there is no indication that [google](/questions/tagged/google) is [blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214363):

> [image]

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283802/let-moderators-mark-tags-as-deprecated