# Remove [redhat]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Excerpt:

> For issues relating to Red Hat platforms, products, and/or services.

[As was done with [google]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178438), [redhat](/questions/tagged/redhat) must go. Those 900 questions should simply be tagged with names of those *platforms, products, and/or services*.

Comment: Relevant: [Blacklist the \[microsoft\] and \[apple\] tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199189/152515)

Comment: Who wants to bet that the majority of those 800 are actually about non-programming-related OS configuration tasks?  Let's look at a cleanup before a retag.